# How get products URL in magento 2.2.5 sql database

Tags: magento2.2, products, sql

I am using magento 2 enterprise edition i am trying to get products URL from sql database for this i have seen catalog_products_entity_varchar but in value attribute column products imgages are given so please help me about this problem

[image: error screeen shoot]

Answer (score 0):

you can get it form url_rewrite table

there are entity_id is product_id and request_path  is display url

Comment: i have no find any table as such name

Comment: Are you looking in magento2 or magento1? becuse in magento it's name url_rewrite and in magento1 core_url_rewrite

Comment: magento 2.2.5 as i mention in title body
can u please send accurate table name..?

Comment: Then you must have url_rewrite table

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following steps.

1. Open the table "eav_attribute" and search the record with this condition 
   "entity_type_id" = 4 and "attribute_code" = sku

[image]

so now you get the row which show the attribute_id for the url_key something like this.

[image]

In demo case it is 121.

2. Now open the "catalog_product_entity_varchar" table and serch the record by 
   "attribute_id" = 121

[image]

And finaly you get the product URL like this one.

[image]

If you are trying to make the query, then you need to write like this :

> SELECT * FROM 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' WHERE 'attribute_id' =
>   121

Comment: with query empty record show

Comment: You need to replace your attribute_id here from the table "eav_attribute"

Comment: @ShanHaider you get your answer or not?

Comment: yes thanks @Dhiren